# How can I get data inside a DIV to appear below other DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div>
   <div class="float-left gutter-right">
      xx
   </div>
   <div class="float-left gutter-right">
      yy
   </div>
</div>
<div>
zz
</div>
```

I would like to have xx and yy appear next to each other and zz appear below. But this is not what is happening.

How can I make it so the zz appears below?

Comment: Yes show us ur CSS first

Comment: add a specific `class` to the xx `div` and `float:left;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Approach 1

Use `float: left` + `clear: both`.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="float-left gutter-right">xx</div>
    <div class="float-left gutter-right">yy</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">zz</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.float-left { float: left; }
div.clear { clear: both; }
```

**Explanation:**

I used the class `float-left` of the first 2 divs so that they may come in one line. Then I add a class of `.clear` to the last div so that I could bring it in a seprate line where it will have no object floating neither left or right of it.

[Demonstration 1.](http://jsfiddle.net/63mqw/)

---

### Approach 2

Use `display: inline`.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <div class="float-left gutter-right inline">xx</div>
    <div class="float-left gutter-right inline">yy</div>
</div>
<div class="clear">zz</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div.inline { display: inline; }
```

**Explanation:**

I have added a class `.inline` to the first 2 divs and applied the style `display: inline` to this class and so those two first div will be displayed inline and then you don't need to `clear:both` the last div.

[Demonstration 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/63mqw/1/)

Answer (score 2):

Use `float:left;` to the `float-left` class, and `clear: both;` to the bottom `div`

**The html:**

```
<div class="float-left gutter-right">
   xx
</div>
<div class="float-left gutter-right">
    yy
</div>
<div id="bellow">
    zz
</div>
```

**The css**

```
.float-left {width: 50%; float: left;}
#bellow { clear: both;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depends of the implementation of your `float-left` class. You need some clearing to get zz under xx and yy.

Answer (score 1):

`CSS`

```
div div:first-child{
    float:left;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are using `float:left` on the `DIV`s that you want to display next to each other, which is ok, but you have to make sure their widths combined is smaller than 100%, so they fit.

Try this:

**HTML**:

```
<div>
   <div class="inline-div">
      xx
   </div>
   <div class="inline-div">
      yy
   </div>
</div>
<div>
zz
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.inline-div {
    float:left;
    width:50%;
}
```

[See the fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/nZYDd/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
    <div class="float-left gutter-right">xx</div>
    <div class="float-left gutter-right">yy</div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div>zz</div>
```

Then make ur css look like this

```
div.float-left { float: left; }
div.clear { clear: both; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This would also work, with any combination of selector and decleration. Add this to your CSS:

```
.gutter-right {
    display: inline;
}
```

or

```
.float-left {
   display: inline-block;
}
```